# Was The Bookkeeper of Oa actually Sinestro?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

I recently read Wrath of the First Lantern and towards the middle the future is shown where a young new Lantern speaks to a person in a cloak who seems to be The Bookkeeper of the Book of Oa.  The young lantern named Lantern Snow asks him to tell him the story that every Lantern learns.

> The one that tells of Hal Jordan defeating the First Lantern.

Now after the story is finished Lantern Snow wants to know what happened to the other lanterns after the events of Wrath of the First Lantern and where they end up.  The cloaked figure tells him of everyone's fate except one, the fate of Sinestro was supposedly burned out of the Book of Oa by the cloaked figure.  As he's saying this he has his hand on the book and it sort of looks like an aged magenta hand.  Is this supposed to imply that he is Sinestro?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I must have been buzzing through when I got to this issue (read it in GLC Volume 3), and it didn't even register withe that the bookkeeper might be Sinestro. Now that issue is retroactively much more awesome!

Comment: I seriously saw somebody edit my question and put dc-movies or something the other day I was like what....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is certainly the implication. When he starts to speak he says "I burned..." then corrects himself.

[image: Green Lantern 20]

If this future ever actually comes to pass is pretty much unknown at this point.

Comment: Ah, not quite... the last panel there drops back to the present. When I'm somewhere with image editing I'll lop it off.

Comment: Yep what Nikolai said.

Answer (score 1):

It's not explicitly stated, but the clear implication is that yes, Toris (the Bookkeeper) is Sinestro;

Green Lantern comic writer [Geoff Johns](http://web.archive.org/web/20130607223831/http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/05/31/geoff-johns-talks-about-ending-green-lantern) all but confirms it by linking the two characters together in this interview...

> "Obviously, Sinestro is an emotional guy and if he shows mercy with
>   Ganthet and Sayd then there’s still hope that one day there’s a way to
>   redeem himself. I don’t know if you read too close, **but there’s a
>   lot of hints about who that Bookkeeper is in Green Lantern #20**"

Comment: I think by saying that he burned.. then quickly changing it to Those pages were burned while having a magenta hand on the book clearly implies that he is in fact Sinestro.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - Oh yeah. You'd have to be the biggest idiot in idiot-town not to get the reference...

Comment: When I first read through it on my phone, downloaded it from Android Play I didn't see the portion where he changed what he said... I just remembered him touching the page and saying something about how the pages were burned.